# Cordova Android- Keep sending AJAX request to the server while the device is in background mode

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to keep performing Ajax request to the server even if the device is in background, I’ve tried the “cordova-plugin-background-mode “ https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode ,
Please see the code below ,but for some reason it doesn’t work

Any help would be appreciated to solve this problem

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function (){
  window.setInterval(function () {
    //Ajax request every 6 S
    }, 6000)
});
```

Comment: What is not working ? How is it behaving? Also, just out of interest, why do you want to do this ?

Comment: It stops sending the Ajax request when the device is in background mode; I need this to check if the user still logged in his/here account, it like a “keep alive request” I send the user ID to the server I store this with creation date, then in the server I run a cron-job to auto change status of users to offline if the creation date of their last request from mobile device is >= 10min form now

Comment: Wow.. You really are handling session management in a strange way.. Why not just rely on the server being the source of truth, and auth checking on the requests ? Otherwise something like a websocket with a persisted connection could give you real time info, but I smell an over complicated solution for a simple service..

Comment: Certainly you’re right, that’s the result when something came up in a project without been thinking of it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It stops sending the Ajax request when the device is in background mode; I need this to check if the user still logged in his/here account

Basically you want your app to consider your users as *online* as long as they have started the app and keep their phones on? If this is true, then you can simply assume they will stay *online forever*.

**When your app is sent to the background, you must do what any other app does: Consider the user is no longer online.** Do not waste user resources and network data from their carrier just to see if the user's phone is still on, this makes no sense at all.

Whenever the app is active and running, you update your database on every request, or every few minutes with a timer if there's no user-initiated network activity.

Comment: Thank you, I accept as answer.
Why I need to keep cheek the user status even if he/she in background?
It’s a taxi application I need to keep tracking the state of user to see if he is online before sending request booking, he can be in background while he driving on road and he can’t always check his phone.
I find a workaround to solve this problem using a background Geolocalisation  , so i consider the driver is no longer online if his device not sending request Lat,Lng to server for 15 min, for instance.